# Using Enum and Switch on Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, if-statement, enums, switch-statement

I have a view with 3 text fields:

1. Current password
2. New password
3. Confirm new password

The requirement is, to check the validity of these passwords, if the conditions are not satisfied, there will be a alert view popup.

1. If user inputs the wrong current password
2. New password must have more than 8 letters
3. the new passwords must match

I used `if`-`else` but it seems not to be suitable, and tried `switch`-`case` instead. But it still doesn't work.

**My code:**

```
NSString *textFromBox1 = [stringArray objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *textFromBox2 = [stringArray objectAtIndex:1];
NSString *textFromBox3 = [stringArray objectAtIndex:2];

enum ErrorCase{
    oldPasswordCase,
    newPasswordLength,
    newPasswordCheck,
};

enum ErrorCase error;

if ([textFromBox1 length] < 2) {
    error = oldPasswordCase;
} else if ([textFromBox2 length] < 8) {
    error = newPasswordLength;
} else if (textFromBox2 != textFromBox3) {
    error = newPasswordCheck;
}

switch (error) {
    case oldPasswordCase:
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"過ち"
                                                        message:@"現在のパスワードが間違っています。"
                                                       delegate:self
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
        break;
    case newPasswordLength:
    {
        UIAlertView *alert2 = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"過ち"
                                                         message:@"パスワードを8文字以上で入力してください。"
                                                        delegate:self
                                               cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                               otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert2 show];

    }
        break;
    case newPasswordCheck:
    {
        UIAlertView *alert3 = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"過ち"
                                                         message:@"新しいパスワードとパスワード（確認）が間違っています。"
                                                        delegate:self
                                               cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                               otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert3 show];
    }
        break;

    default:
        break;
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Objective-C the argument in a `switch` statement must be an integer.

Use the `NS_ENUM` macro to declare the enum as integer

```
typedef NS_ENUM (NSInteger, ErrorCase) {
    oldPasswordCase,
    newPasswordLength,
    newPasswordCheck,
};
```

Then declare the error variable

```
ErrorCase error;
```

And as mentioned in Mateusz's answer you have to use `isEqualToString` to compare two strings.

Edit: Your `if - else` chain is not exhaustive which could cause unexpected behavior. Either add a default `none` case and assign it to `error` or make sure that the `if - else` chain considers all cases (thanks to Idali for the hint).

Comment: Thank you, so do i have assign the int value like "oldPasswordCase = 1" or just keep assign to error variable like default?

Comment: No you don't have to, the default value for the first case is 0, for the second 1 and so on.

Comment: It will be also useful to always map 0 to an unknownCase, this will result code-safe against  if(error) {...} and also distinguish case when error never get set vs 0 case.

Answer (score 1):

this code is checking if two pointers are the same not two strings:

```
if (textFromBox2 != textFromBox3)
```

to compare strings you should use:

```
[textFromBox2 isEqualToString: textFromBox3]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do like this without enum:

```
NSString *textFromBox1 = [stringArray objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *textFromBox2 = [stringArray objectAtIndex:1];
NSString *textFromBox3 = [stringArray objectAtIndex:2];
NSString *alertString = nil;
if ([textFromBox1 length] < 2) {
    alertString = @"現在のパスワードが間違っています。";
} else if ([textFromBox2 length] < 8) {
    alertString = @"パスワードを8文字以上で入力してください。";
} else if (![textFromBox2 isEqualToString:textFromBox3]) {
    alertString = @"新しいパスワードとパスワード（確認）が間違っています。";
}

if (alertString) {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"過ち"
                                                    message:alertString
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}
```